# Calling a function on different class names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, refactoring

I'd like to know is there a simpler way to call a function on different classes aside from listing them one by one?

```
  function linkBlock($blockName) {
    // DO SOMETHING
  }

  linkBlock(".class1");
  linkBlock(".class2");
  linkBlock(".class3");
  linkBlock(".class4");
```

Comment: `[".class1", ".class2", ".class3", ".class4"].forEach( linkBlock )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are asking for a loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    linkBlock(".class"+i);
}
```

Or if the parameter of that function is a DOM selector, you could also use

```
linkBlock(".class1, .class2, .class3, .class4");
```

but in that case you probably should rather fix your markup so that those elements share a class.